# How to subtract number from the input box for Grand Total?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```js
function credit() {
  //storing value of grandTotal in txtGrandTotal.
  var txtGrandTotal = $("#txtGraTot").val();

  //here resetting value of grandTotal to 0.00
  var txtGraTotal = document.getElementById('txtGraTot').value = '0.00';

  //entering deduction amount
  var txtCredit = document.getElementById('txtCreditAmt').value;

  //subtracting values
  var lclRes = (parseFloat(txtGrandTotal) - parseFloat(txtCredit)).toFixed(2);

  //again storing values to Textbox GrandTotal
  $("#txtGraTot").val(lclRes);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtCreditAmt" oninput="credit();">
<input type="text" id="txtGraTot">
```

The result is not as I expected. If I enter `3` in `txtCredit` input box then value deducting from the Grand Total is `100 - 3 = 97`. But if I enter the dot(.) again the result is `97 - . = 94`. Why it is happening?

Comment: I don't think oninput() is the correct event to use. This will call the credit function each and every time you input something in the inputbox.

Comment: I used onkeyup, onkeypress. is there any other event to do the operation.

Comment: Try using onfocusout

Comment: First of all, you're resetting the value to a value of string type... You have to turn that into a number. Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: you really need to clean up your code :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not storing the original value of grand total in a separate variable. So, when the `input` event fires, it updates the grand total every time. Here's what is going on:

```
                  Grand total     Credit
Original state:        100          ___
Press 3       :         97           3      oninput invoked, grand total = (100 - 3)
Press .       :         94           3.     oninput invoked, grand total = (97 - 3.)
```

The quick and easy (but not the ideal) solution is to store the original value of grand total in a separate variable, and use that every time `input` event fires. My solution is to store that value in a `data-total` attribute (`$("#txtGraTot").data("total")`) but you can have something else there. Just make sure that you are subtracting from original value, and not from the current value in the text box.

```
// Save the original value of grand total in an attribute for future use.
if ($("#txtGraTot").data("total") === undefined) {
  $("#txtGraTot").data("total", txtGrandTotal);
} else {
  // else, get the original grand total value.
  txtGrandTotal = $("#txtGraTot").data("total");
}
```

```js
function credit(){

    //storing value of grandTotal in txtGrandTotal.
    var txtGrandTotal = $("#txtGraTot").val();
    
    // Save the original value of grand total in an attribute for future use.
    if ($("#txtGraTot").data("total") === undefined) {
      $("#txtGraTot").data("total", txtGrandTotal);
    } else {
      // else, get the original grand total value.
      txtGrandTotal = $("#txtGraTot").data("total");
    }

    //here resetting value of grandTotal to 0.00
    var txtGraTotal = document.getElementById('txtGraTot').value = '0.00';

    //entering deduction amount
    var txtCredit = document.getElementById('txtCreditAmt').value;

    //subtracting values
    var lclRes = (parseFloat(txtGrandTotal) - parseFloat(txtCredit)).toFixed(2);

    //again storing values to Textbox GrandTotal
    $("#txtGraTot").val(lclRes);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtCreditAmt" oninput="credit();">
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtGraTot">
```

Comment: Working as fine but after entering the value to the text box as working if I backspace and erase the value from the text box that I am getting NaN in grand total.

Comment: @beta Yes, I had noticed that. You will need some sort of validation to check if both numbers are valid `isNaN` before calculating the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but that should make sense.

**Edited**

Add the feature that after you press the enter button, calculate and reset txtCreditAmt.

```js
function credit(){

    //subtracting values
    var lclRes = (parseFloat($("#txtGraTot").val()) - parseFloat($("#txtCreditAmt").val())).toFixed(2);

    //again storing values to Textbox GrandTotal
    $("#txtGraTot").val(lclRes);
}

$('#txtCreditAmt').keypress(function(e){

  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      credit();
      $("#txtCreditAmt").val('');
      return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtCreditAmt" onblur="credit();">
<input type="text" id="txtGraTot" value="100">
```

Comment: This is happening correctly but after clicking on the 2nd textbox.

Comment: Hi, bro are you there?